# Overriding CSS of TinyMCE editor in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE 5 for my React project. I want to customize the editor and I want to do things like for eg: editing border property or adding box shadow to toolbar. I tried adding css using content_css property but it isn't working. Is there any other work around for it?

edit:
Here's how I want it to look like in the end
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0QQE.jpg)

I was able to add custom icons. Only problem I'm facing is modifying the css. I want to bring the toolbar down, add shadow effect, make icons little smaller and reduce the width of the toolbar. I also tried using styled-components to override CSS but it didn't work. Is there any alternative to override CSS?

Comment: if you can add the code ,how you are using and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 5):

You can bring the toolbar down using `toolbar_location: "bottom"`.

Regarding CSS, you can override the default CSS with your own styles using `content_css`. For example:

```
content_css: "/mycontent.css";
```

Or you can override specific parts of it using `content_style`. For example:

```
content_style: "body { font-family: Arial; }";
```

Also see:

- [Customizing the TinyMCE toolbar](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-toolbar)
- [content_css](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css) & [content_style](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style)

Comment: How do you think will work with React-tinymce? does it go with init property? @Ben Long

Comment: Yes, you should be able to configure these options within the init.

Comment: yes it works, example:

init={{
     content_style: 'h1 { color: red }'
}}